# Organisms with one, two, or more than two biological parents

Tags: reproduction, theoretical-biology

I am interested in the generic names of organisms with one, two, or more than two biological parents. I don't know if the latter possibility is possible in nature, but if it could be, it would certainly be interesting.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Do you mean terms for referring to "species where reproduction mode leads individuals to have one, two or more parents"? Main cases will be roughly covered under the terms "sexual reproduction" and "asexual reproduction".

Comment: Can you please point me to a Wikipedia article with some pictures. I was wondering whether three, or more, is possible, or purely fictional. Thanks.

Comment: You might first want to read about [asexual reproduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asexual_reproduction) and [sexual reproduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_reproduction). I am not aware of a case where an individual has properly more than two parents. However, [double fertilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_fertilization) in angiosperm might more or less be considered as such.

Comment: Very interesting Remi, I was not aware of double fertilization. Thanks for the pointer. :-)

Comment: @Remi.b I wouldn't consider double fertilization in angiosperms to be more than two parents because both sperm cells are coming from the same parent plant. Of course, self-pollinating flowering plants can undergo double fertilization as well -- in those instances, there is only one parent.